# Create/Write to file x86 Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have been trying to teach myself some 32-bit x86 (NASM). I am trying to have a user input a file name, open/create the file, then take a user's message and write that message to the file. I have gone through it in GDB and all syscalls returned correctly. After the program runs the file appears to be created improperly and nothing is written to it. I ahev seen some of the other question that are similar but my code seems to be nearly the same as their's so I can't seem to figure out what the heck is going on.

Here is my noob code:

```
global _start
section .data
  fmsg:  db "Enter Filename: ", 0
  .len:  equ $ - fmsg
  umsg:  db "Enter message: ", 0
  .len:  equ $ - umsg
  buff:  times 50 db 0  ;array for user string
  .blen: equ $ - buff
  fname: times 50 db 0 ;array for filename
  .flen: equ $ - fname

  ;modes
  O_RDONLY: db 0        ;read-only
  O_WRONLY: db 1        ;wirte-only
  O_RDWR:   db 2        ;read and write

  ;flags
  O_CREAT:  dw 100o     ;create file if file doesnt exists
  O_TRUNC:  dw 1000o    ;truncate file
  O_APPEND: dw 2000o    ;append to file


section .bss
  fd:   resd 1          ;file descriptor
  bret: resd 1          ;read buffer return value
  fret: resd 1          ;read filename return value
  tmp:  resd 1          ;temp 4 byte variable

section .text
_start:

fprompt:               ;Print prompt
  mov eax, 0x4         ;syscall 4 - write()
  mov ebx, 0x1         ;file desc 1 - stdout
  mov ecx, fmsg        ;print message
  mov edx, fmsg.len    ;length of message
  int 80h              ;syscall interupt

filein:
  mov eax, 0x3          ;syscall 3 - read()
  mov ebx, 0x0          ;file desc 0 - stdin
  mov ecx, fname        ;dst buffer
  mov edx, fname.flen   ;length of buffer
  int 80h               ;syscall interupt
  mov [fret], eax       ;save return value to file return variable
  cmp eax, edx          ;read max bytes or more?
  jb  fileopen          ;jmp is bytes read < max
  mov bl, [ecx+eax-1]   ;grab last byte @ last index before '\0'
  cmp bl, 10            ;does it = '\n' ?
  je  clean1
  inc DWORD [fret]      ;len++

clean1:               ;loop to clear excess input, if any
  mov eax, 0x3        ;syscall 3 - read()
  mov ebx, 0x0        ;file desc 0 - stdin
  mov ecx, tmp        ;temp buffer
  mov edx, 0x1        ;read only 1 byte
  int 80h             ;;syscall interupt
  test eax, eax       ;EOF?
  jz  fileopen        ;Yes, jump to pback
  mov al, [tmp]       ;put character into lower 8 bits of EAX
  cmp al, 10          ;is it = to lf ?
  jne clean1          ;no, jump to begining of loop

fileopen:
  mov eax, 0x05
  mov ebx, fname      ;filename
  or  ecx, O_CREAT    ;if it doesn't exist create the file
  or  ecx, O_TRUNC    ;truncate
  mov edx, O_WRONLY   ;write only
  int 80h             ;syscall interupt
  mov [fd], eax       ;save file descripor

prompt2:
  mov eax, 0x4         ;syscall 4 - write()
  mov ebx, 0x1         ;file desc 1 - stdout
  mov ecx, umsg        ;print message
  mov edx, umsg.len    ;length of message
  int 80h

userin:
  mov eax, 0x3          ;syscall 3 - read()
  mov ebx, 0x0          ;file desc 0 - stdin
  mov ecx, buff         ;dst buffer
  mov edx, buff.blen    ;length of buffer
  int 80h               ;syscall interupt
  mov [bret], eax       ;save return value to buff return variable
  cmp eax, edx          ;read max bytes or more?
  jb  writetofile       ;jmp is bytes read < max
  mov bl, [ecx+eax-1]   ;grab last byte @ last index before '\0'
  cmp bl, 10            ;does it = '\n' ?
  je  clean2
  inc DWORD [bret]      ;len++

clean2:               ;loop to clear excess input, if any
  mov eax, 0x3        ;syscall 3 - read()
  mov ebx, 0x0        ;file desc 0 - stdin
  mov ecx, tmp        ;temp buffer
  mov edx, 0x1        ;read only 1 byte
  int 80h             ;syscall
  test eax, eax       ;EOF?
  jz  writetofile     ;Yes, jump to pback
  mov al, [tmp]       ;put character into lower 8 bits of EAX
  cmp al, 10          ;is it = to lf ?
  jne clean2          ;no, jump to begining of loop


writetofile:
  mov eax, 0x4         ;syscall 4 - write()
  mov ebx, [fd]        ;file desc 1 - stdout
  mov ecx, buff        ;print message
  mov edx, [bret]      ;length of message
  int 80h              ;syscall interupt

closefile:
  mov eax, 0x6      ;syscall 6 - close()
  mov ebx, [fd]     ;file desc
  int 80h           ;syscall interupt

exit:               ;return 0
  mov eax, 1        ;syscall 1 - exit()
  mov ebx, 0        ;return val
  int 80h           ;syscall interupt
```

Here is an example of what I get after running it:
[image: Output]

The file "test.txt?" shows up and also shows up as an executable even though I set only read/write for the file. Even when I try to open it there is nothing there. Any thoughts? Also As I mentioned, i am new and teaching myself so if you have any good tips on improvement for other areas of the program please let me know! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have multiple errors (or one big one) in the following three lines of code:

```
or  ecx, O_CREAT    ;if it doesn't exist create the file
or  ecx, O_TRUNC    ;truncate
mov edx, O_WRONLY   ;write only
```

The problem:

What values do the registers `ecx` and `edx` have after these lines?

You perform two `or` operations with the `ecx` register but obviously it is not initialized at that moment!

This means that you can be sure that the bits representing `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` (whatever these values mean - see below) are set but you don't know which values the other bits have.

The `O_WRONLY` bit should be set in `ecx`, not in `edx`. `edx` should contain the desired file mode instead.

Unfortunately there are two different types of assembler - I don't know which type NASM is of:

- One type of assembler would interpret the first instruction as: `or ecx, [O_CREAT]`
- The other type would interpret it as: `or ecx, address_of(O_CREAT)`

In the first case the instruction `mov edx, O_WRONLY` will read four bytes starting with the `O_WRONLY` byte into the `edx` register so `edx` will have the value `0x400201` (O_CREAT*0x10000+O_RDWR*0x100+O_WRONLY).

In the second case `edx` will contain the address of `O_WRONLY` rather than the value.

The value will be wrong in any case.

Comment: NASM/FASM/YASM works as expected, without `[]` no memory is accessed, so those `O_` are immediate constants (either addresses or "equs"), depends how the OP defined them. (only TASM/MASM/emu8086 will try to *guess* memory access) .. Now I did check how OP defined them, and those are not constants, but address labels, so that's yet another bug. I wonder how he didn't see in `gdb` that argument is wrong ahead of service call.

Comment: Thanks for the walk through! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Storing your mode constants in memory is really inefficient, even if you were doing it right (which you aren't).

You could trace what system calls you're actually making by running `strace ./writefile`.

---

You use `O_RDONLY: db 0` to store a byte of static data (in the read/write section instead of `.rodata` for some reason).  Instead, you should define assembler constants with `equ`:

```
  O_RDONLY equ 0
  O_WRONLY equ 1
  O_RDWR   equ 2

  O_CREAT  equ 100o     ;create file if file doesnt exists
  O_TRUNC  equ 1000o    ;truncate file
  O_APPEND equ 2000o    ;append to file
```

Then you can write

```
mov  ecx, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY
mov  edx, 0777o                        ; mode is the permission bits if open() creates the file
```

See [the `open(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to learn how its args work.

The assembler will do the OR for you at assemble time, instead of having the CPU do 2 loads from memory.

---

**What you actually wrote**:

```
  or  ecx, O_CREAT    ;if it doesn't exist create the file
  or  ecx, O_TRUNC    ;truncate
```

assembles to two `or ecx, imm32` instructions, which OR the addresses of the two `dw` locations into the original value of `ecx`.  If you had written

```
  movzx  ecx, word [O_CREAT]
  or      cx, [O_TRUNC]
  or      cx, [O_WRONLY]
```

your code would have worked, but that would be really silly.  (And on some CPUs cause a partial-register stall when something reads the full `ecx` after you wrote only the low 16 bits.)

If you'd written `or ecx, [O_TRUNC]`, it would do a 32-bit load, so you'd effectively be doing `ecx |=  (2000o << 16) | 1000o`.  i.e. the word stored at `O_APPEND` would be ORed into the high 16 bits of ECX, where it may have a different meaning.

Similarly, `mov edx, O_WRONLY` assembles to `mov edx, imm32`, where the address is the immediate.  This is why you ended up with weird garbage for the file mode (including the sticky bit set).

**Use a debugger**.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! Helped a lot!